# Could the bountied question list contain all items when less than 5-8?

Tags: feature-request, bountied-tab

**Note:** This is a low priority feature-request, but I've made it, hoping it will require only a one line change in the server engine and would slightly improve the user experience.

---

When navigating from the main page to the bountied items, would it be possible to show **all questions** when there are less than say five?  For example, on Meta today we see:

[image: Image of Top Questions]

But there are only *three* questions with a bounty:

[image: Image of All Bountied Questions]

Could all of the questions be shown **if there are less than say five** to provide a slightly less complicate user interface?  Especially as this view doesn't show the question text (only the title)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing bounty question is at -48 score. The "home page" of a Stack Exchange site will filter out all questions that fall below a certain threshold. This is -4 score for main Q&A sites, and -8 for Meta sites. This is because the home page is meant to highlight quality content, so that a brand new visitor will see good stuff. It's rare that a bounty question will have such a negatively rated score.

The ideal expectation is that something with a very low net score is poor quality content. The presence of a bounty doesn't alter the quality of a post, so I don't think that the featured tab should special-case itself on the score-based filter.

Comment: While I totally understand that it a question with -48 score should have less visibility, I still think that the user interface is unnecessarily complicated given that there are *only three* (now four) questions. If there were twelve questions, then sure, leave the -48 post on the full list, but why not simplify the user interface, consolidate such a short list and remove the "Browse the complete list" link when there are only four choices.

Comment: Further, I realize that a question with 48 downvotes may not be desirable, *by you*, to feature, but **someone did give up reputation for the bounty**.  Why relegate it to a less visible location?

Comment: @MTibbits It's unnecessarily complicated to devise an exception like that for an otherwise simple rule, when the use case is fairly rare to occur (it isn't often that there are very negative bounty posts, and it isn't often that this will simultaneously happen when there are only a tiny number of bounties). It's only less visible on one page, they still have the benefit of being on the featured tab everywhere else on the site, so I don't think it's as if they're wasting their reputation away for naught.

Comment: Note, I tend to overuse **bold** and *italics* merely as a means for emphasis.  I stand by the statement "this is a **really low priority** request" -- and I'm not .  As it happens, *I also downvoted the -48 post.*  I'm not emphatic that this change occur, I merely believe it would simplify the user experience, slightly.