# Featured tab showing incorrect number

Tags: support, bountied-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could featured question list contain all items when less than 5-8?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99900/could-featured-question-list-contain-all-items-when-less-than-5-8)

The featured tab here on meta is showing a highlighted `4`, which I assumed to mean there would be 4 posts inside.  How wrong was I?

[image]

Have I missed something here or is this a bug?  It wasn't just a single occasion, the issue remained for multiple refreshes.

Comment: The fourth question that isn't appearing has like 45 downvotes. We don't show questions by default that are rated *that* poorly by the community. Takes an extra click to see those.

Comment: I see.  So if the heavily downvoted question isn't going to be displayed by default, wouldn't it make sense to have the highlighted number on the tab only reflect what you are going to initially see?

Comment: Maybe. Except that the number is indicating the *total* number of featured questions. You didn't miss the bold explanatory text and link at the bottom, did you? The part where it offers you to "browse the complete list"?

Comment: I didn't miss it, no. I misinterpreted it, and feel slightly foolish for not clicking it before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on that: Looking for more featured questions? Browse the [complete list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured)

and you will get all of them

[image]